# Dropbox-friendly password manager for XP, OSX and Android

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, android, password-management, keepass

I've been using Password Safe for years, but there are two problems:

1. It doesn't play nicely with Dropbox - I constantly get conflicts as it keeps the password file open on both ends.
2. I now use a Macbook Pro for work, and have an Android phone.

Is there a password manager that works well on all three platforms, and also doesn't have the file syncing/conflict problem with Dropbox? (Or it can have a different cloud solution...)

I see that KeePass has "unofficial" ports for Android and Mac OS X, but they look, um, immature. Native apps (ie, not Mono) would be preferred...

Answer (score 3):

Check this comparison: http://www.tested.com/news/feature/3138-the-best-password-managers-for-your-android-phone/

I use keeppass with keeppassdroid on my android device. Big advantage for me is that it's opensource and free.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) It works on multiple OS and phones and is relatively cheap. TONS of options if you go to Premium or Enterprise.

Comment: Looks to fit the bill pretty well. $1/mo for the Android edition. I guess I can afford that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword/win)? I've used it on a Mac running OS X with Dropbox for quite a while now.  They also have a Windows version.

Comment: Looks good but very pricey - $70 for windows plus Mac. Looks like the Android version had some issues and us read only anyway.